# CFStringGetCStringPtr returns NULL on iOS7

Tags: ios7, cfstring

I have the following code in my Application:

```
static void foo(CFStringRef str)
{
    CFStringEncoding encoding = CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
    const char * cString = CFStringGetCStringPtr(str, encoding);

    //.....                
}
```

It's been around since iOS 5, and always worked.
Since iOS 7 release, `CFStringGetCStringPtr` returns `NULL`.
Adding the following code, have solved it:

```
if (cString==NULL)
{
    cString = [
        ((NSString *)str) cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]
    ];
}
```

Still, I would like to know if anyone knows what causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFStringGetCStringPtr() isn't guaranteed to return non-NULL. From the docs (emphasis added):

> Whether or not this function returns a valid pointer or NULL depends on many factors, all of which depend on how the string was created and its properties. **In addition, the function result might change between different releases and on different platforms.** So do not count on receiving a non-NULL result from this function under any circumstances.

Always have a fallback to CFStringGetCString(), but even better, use Objective-C and NSString's helper methods (e.g. UTF8String).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, that what I end up doing :)